# Sum of infinite number of exponential random variables

Tags: markov-chains, exponential-distribution

Let

$S_n \sim Exp(n)$

for $n = 1,2,...$ and define

$\zeta = \sum_{i=1}^\infty S_n$.

Is it true that $\mathbb{P}(\zeta = \infty) = 1$ ?

We have $\mathbb{E}(\zeta) = \infty$ by a quick calculation - how to build on this idea?

---

**Context**: Continuous-time Markov Chains. We have a $Q$-matrix

$q_{n, n+1} = n \lambda$

$q_{n,0} = \mu$

We are required to show that the Markov Chain is non-explosive. We could show that the origin is recurrent, or that the explosion time $\zeta$ is infinite w.p. 1. This second approach leads to my question.

It makes sense to me that $\zeta$ should be always infinite, or always finite - so $\mathbb{E}(\zeta) = \infty$ would suffice to show non-explosiveness. But I don't know how to show this.

Comment: The classical approach is to note that $S_n=\frac1nX_n$ where $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. standard normal and that $$\zeta_n=\sum_{k=1}^nS_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k(X_k-1)$$ Now, you should be able to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k(X_k-1)$$ converges in $L^2$, hence almost surely, and to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's true.

A more classical approach is to show that if $S_i\sim\exp(\lambda_i)$ then
$$Ee^{-\xi}=\prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\lambda_i}}=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\right)}$$
and observe that the denominator is infinite if and only if $E\xi=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda_i}=\infty$ (see below why). In this case $e^{-\xi}$ is a nonnegative random variable with mean zero and is hence zero with probability one. This is equivalent to the statement that $P(\xi=\infty)=1$.

Hint for showing when the denominator is infinite:
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\le \prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_i}\right)\le \exp\left({\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\lambda_i}}\right)\ .$$
The left side follows by induction while the right side follows from the fact that $1+x\le e^x$ for all $x$.